# how to check for WebAuthn platform-type authenticators?

Tags: webauthn

So trying to integrate WebAuthN. And if for platform-independent(FIDO2 security key) check is easier(whether webauthN is supported in general - we proceed, maybe user plug USB key later), I cannot find a way to check for platform-dependent(Windows Hello, fingerprints scanner, etc) authenticators. [`isUserVerifyingPlatformAuthenticatorAvailable()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PublicKeyCredential/isUserVerifyingPlatformAuthenticatorAvailable) looked as all I need but

```
window.PublicKeyCredential.isUserVerifyingPlatformAuthenticatorAvailable()
  .then(() => true)
  .catch(() => false)
  .then((x) => console.log(x))
```

always returns true for my MacBook(Chrome, Firefox, Safari). Besides MacBook does not have any authenticator and trying to proceed with param of

```
"authenticatorSelection": {
    "authenticatorAttachment" : "platform", 
    "requireResidentKey":false, 
    "userVerification":"preferred"
}
```

ends up with "This device does not support the type of security key requested by this website." message(and my MacBook definitely has no fingerprint scanners so it's reasonable!)

Saw [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63492633/webauthn-is-it-possible-to-see-the-available-platform-authenticators) but only with advices to use this `isUserVerifyingPlatformAuthenticatorAvailable()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`isUserVerifyingPlatformAuthenticatorAvailable()` returns a Promise of boolean so your code should look more like:

```
window.PublicKeyCredential.isUserVerifyingPlatformAuthenticatorAvailable()
  .then(isAvailable => isAvailable)
  .catch(err => false)
  .then(result => console.log("Platform authenticator is available: " + result));
```

MDN article here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PublicKeyCredential/isUserVerifyingPlatformAuthenticatorAvailable

Comment: ...or even without `.then(isAvailable => isAvailable)`. Yes, you're completely right, what a silly mistake I did! Thanks!